# GPO shows as being applied but the settings were not implemented

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I created a new GPO to change users IE favorites, previously I had 6 different GPOs to manage different favorites for different kinds of users and users in different locations, but recently my boss decided that we should just consolidate them instead of creating a 7th for another unique situation. I created a new GPO, configured it accordingly and applied it to the desired OUs and set the new GPO to be enforced. I then deleted all the links to the old favorites GPOs.

Our network has 2003 server, 2008, 2008 r2, vista, and win 7.

The problem I'm running into is that some of the users are taking the new GPO settings and some are not. I have users who are in the same OU who are getting different results, some of their computers will take the new GPO and some will not.

On my profile when I run gpresult the new GPO is listed under Applied Group Policy Objects but the settings do not take effect. I've run gpupdate /force with no luck, rebooted 3 times, and it's been 4 hours.

I was able to logon to a terminal services server and the new favorites were applied to my profile there, but they just won't take effect on my normal workstation.

Our DC's are all 2008 r2, our terminal services server is 2003 x64, my workstation is win 7 x64, my boss's workstation is win 7 x64 and the policy is applied to his computer with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further troubleshooting and more research it looks like the problem is, the computers that aren't accepting the changes have been upgraded to IE 10. Everyone using IE 9 and below take the policy with no problems, but IE 10 requires new GPO administrative templates.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37009

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer "accepted." I'm glad you posted this, because I was scratching my head over what it could be myself.